# a good game for them to lose

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, infinitives

I was thinking about the structure **'adjective+noun+for+noun+infinitive'** and was wondering whether the structure itself could be used in two ways.

Consider the following sentences:

a. **This is a good game for Manchester United to lose**. If they lose this game, they'll learn a lesson and will start getting their act together.

b. **This is a good game for Manchester United to lose.** If they lose this game, they'll be eliminated and we won't have to play against them.

In (a) the speaker has the interests of Manchester United in mind.

In (b) the speaker doesn't have the interests of Manchester United in mind. He wants them to be eliminated so his team won't have to play against them. It will be good for him if Man United loses.

I think (a) works. I have stronger doubts about (b).

Do you find both acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The second is fine if you are speaking with intended irony. And there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of both of the expressions is correct.

In the first expression, speaker has vested interested of Manchester United in mind, as you have noted in your text.

Second expression is incorrect, with regards to the meaning you are trying to convey. I would instead say, I hope they lose this game.(so that we don't have to face them in future.)